# How to dynamically query couch db

Tags: php, couchdb, cloudant

I am using php-on-couch library to retrieve data from couchdb
I want to retrieve basing on where condition. I want data according to the user who is signed in. My code below retrieves a view called accounts but i want to be retrieving without creating views on couchdb. Any help is highly appreciated

```
try {
    $doc = $client->asArray()->getView('accounts', 'accounts');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->code() == 404) {
        echo "View not found\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " (errcode=" . $e->getCode() . ")\n";
    }
    exit(1);
}
print_r($doc);
```

is there a better way to dynamically create a view on retrieving just like mysql does?

Answer (score 1):

using [php-on-couch](https://github.com/PHP-on-Couch/PHP-on-Couch/blob/master/doc/couch_client-view.md) you can do this

```
try {

    $opts = array("include_docs" => true, "key" => "your user name");
    $doc = $client->setQueryParameters($opts)->getView("accounts", "accounts");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->code() == 404) {
        echo "Account not found\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . " (errcode=" . $e->getCode() . ")\n";
    }
    exit(1);
}
print_r($doc);
```

Make sure you emit the username as the key in the accounts view. Couch db will search in all accounts in the view and give you the doc that contains your username.

```
emit(doc.username, doc);
```

Hope it helps the rest of you using couchdb in php